# Horizontal scrolling page links don't work from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section within my page that scrolls horizontally with the help of some Javascript. The issue is the links to these horizonal sections don't work if I reference them from another page. The working example is here ("What We Offer" sub links in the main navigation):
http://fitnessacademysurrey.cloudlevel.me

If I navigate to the blog page and then use the "What We Offer" sub-links, they don't do anything.

Here's the code for the links:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var sildeNum = $('.page').length,
    wrapperWidth = 100 * sildeNum,
    slideWidth = 100/sildeNum;
$('.wrapper').width(wrapperWidth + '%'); 
$('.page').width(slideWidth + '%');

$('a.scrollitem').click(function(){
    $('a.scrollitem').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $('#nav-subnav ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('.panelHeading').addClass('hidden');
    $("a.scrollitem").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        $("#nav-subnav ul li:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").addClass("active"),
        $(".panelHeading:nth-child("+(index+2)+")").removeClass("hidden");
    });

    $('#nextLink').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#previousLink').removeClass('disabled');
    if($('#nav-subnav ul li.active').is(':last-child'))
        $('#nextLink').addClass('disabled');

    if($('#nav-subnav ul li.active').is(':first-child'))
        $('#previousLink').addClass('disabled');

    var slideNumber = $($(this).attr('href')).index('.page'),
        margin = slideNumber * -100 + '%';

    $('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},500);
    return false;

  });
});
$( function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash.length > 1) {
    $("[href='" + hash + "']").click();
  }
});
```

previousLink and nextLink are for additional navigation, but I don't think this is relevant.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is you use JavaScript to scroll the page so you need to add code that reads the hash and finds the right link and clicks it.

```
$( function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash.length > 1) {
        $("[href='" + hash + "']").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code (question updated) but it makes no difference. Have I missed something? I'm new to JS, as you probably guessed.